# What happens if Earth loses its magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, geophysics, geomagnetism

Earth's magnetic field is shifting at a high speed does this mean earth will lose its magnetic field and if it does are we in danger or if it doesn't what are consequences of the poles shifting

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) for details.

> The Earth's magnetic field serves to deflect most of the solar wind, whose charged particles would otherwise strip away the ozone layer that protects the Earth from harmful ultraviolet radiation. One stripping mechanism is for gas to be caught in bubbles of magnetic field, which are ripped off by solar winds. Calculations of the loss of carbon dioxide from the atmosphere of Mars, resulting from scavenging of ions by the solar wind, indicate that the dissipation of the magnetic field of Mars caused a near total loss of its atmosphere.

A loss of the atmosphere eventually.